# ViewModel-View Binding in Universal Windows Apps

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

In WPF model binding could be achieved by placing a `DataTemplate` with the viewmodel and view types in your app.xaml. You could then just bind a viewmodel to a contentpresenter and your view would change if you changed your view model through some kind of event.

Here's the old code:

App.xaml (AView and BView are just user controls)

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:AViewModel}">
        <views:ViewA/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:BViewModel}">
        <views:ViewB/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then on some kind of child view that contained the current context:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
```

(Much like https://stackoverflow.com/a/22376718/82333)

However datatemplate syntax no longer works. I've read up on x:bind, but doing a basic replace to the viewmodel type doesn't fix it.

Using this syntax:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ViewAKey" x:DataType="viewModels:AViewModel">
        <views:ViewA/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ViewBKey" x:DataType="viewModels:BViewModel">
        <views:ViewB/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Causes several errors:

Visual studio complains that the view models are not in the namespaces I supplied.

`XBF generation error code 0x09c4`.

What is the equivalent syntax for this operation in Windows 10 Universal Apps?

Comment: Well I had a windows 8.1 wpf app that was working then I moved the code over to a windows 10 universal app and the `Application.Resources` was no longer valid and I was receiving strange error messages.

Comment: If there is no DataTemplate what is type of ContentTemplate property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WPF, the `DataType` is a dependency property which can be retrieved in runtime.

In UWP, the `x:DataType` is compile-time property, you cannot get the value in runtime. `x:DataType` is working with `{x:Bind}`. While using `x:DataType` in `Application.Resources`, it will raise `XBF generation error` as compiler can't generate code. `{x:Bind}` depends on code generation, if you use {x:Bind} in a resource dictionary, the resource dictionary needs to have a code-behind class. And then you can re-use the resource dictionary by instantiating its type instead of referencing its filename. For more information about how to use `{x:Bind}` in a resource dictionary, see [Resource dictionaries with {x:Bind}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210946.aspx#resource_dictionaries_with_x_bind).

If we need to switch the DataTemplate based on the model type, we need to use [DataTemplateSelector class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector).

See the similar case: [How to associate view with viewmodel or multiple DataTemplates for ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252915/how-to-associate-view-with-viewmodel-or-multiple-datatemplates-for-viewmodel/33293716#33293716) for a sample about how to map the data type and data template in UWP through `DataTemplateSelector`.

Comment: This seems a far cry from the old syntax, and much more complicated - I attempted to implement it and had problems with the datatemplateselector item argument always returning null. I'll try again later and see if I get anywhere else but so far no dice :(